# How can I burn-in subtitles to a file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a file called test.m4a and test.srt in the same folder.

How can I burn in the subtitles to m4a?

The output I am getting is :

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ ./ffmpeg -i test.m4v -vf subtitles=test.srt out.m4v
ffmpeg version 2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  8 2014 19:37:09 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fca6201e000] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fca6201e000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: none (drmi / 0x696D7264), 640x478, 1389 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fca6201e000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Subtitle: none (p608 / 0x38303670), 853x478, 0 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2014-06-09 19:13:04
    title           : Day 1: 2:00 A.M. - 3:00 A.M.
    artist          : 24
    album_artist    : 24
    album           : 24
    genre           : Drama
    track           : 3
    disc            : 1/1
    compilation     : 0
    gapless_playback: 0
    date            : 2001-11-20T08:00:00Z
    copyright       : © 2001 Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation
    description     : Jack verifies the key card was encrypted on Nina's computer.
    show            : 24
    episode_id      : 1AFF02 
    season_number   : 1
    episode_sort    : 3
    media_type      : 10
    synopsis        : Kimberly and Janet find themselves in great danger and must look for an escape route.  In her search for Kimberly, Teri has found help from Janet's father Alan York.  Meanwhile, Palmer attends a secret meeting about disturbing news that is about to break,
    iTunMOVI        : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    : <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
                    : <plist version="1.0">
                    : <dict>
                    :   <key>asset-info</key>
                    :   <dict>
                    :       <key>closed-captioned</key>
                    :       <true/>
                    :       <key>file-size</key>
                    :       <integer>484838754</integer>
                    :       <key>flavor</key>
                    :       <string>4:640x480LC-128</string>
                    :       <key>screen-format</key>
                    :       <string>widescreen</string>
                    :   </dict>
                    : </dict>
                    : </plist>
                    : 
  Duration: 00:42:30.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1521 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (drms / 0x736D7264), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-09 19:13:04
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: none (drmi / 0x696D7264), 640x478, 1389 kb/s, SAR 4:3 DAR 1280:717, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-09 19:13:04
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: none (p608 / 0x38303670), 853x478, 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-09 19:13:04
      handler_name    : Apple Closed Caption Media Handler
    Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg), 1400x1400 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fca61e133e0] No such filter: 'subtitles'
Error opening filters!
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like [the wiki page mentions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo), your ffmpeg build needs to be compiled with the `--enable-libass` option for the subtitle filter to work. Yours seems to be a build which unfortunately does not have that.

The easiest way would be to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Then install ffmpeg:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Then, try again:

```
ffmpeg -i test.m4v -vf subtitles=test.srt -c:a copy out.m4v
```

Make sure to read the [H.264 encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) to learn how to set the output quality.

---

Note that you cannot convert files that are DRM-encrypted, like the one in your example (see video codec `drmi`). This is an [open ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1800) for ffmpeg, but unlikely to be resolved.

Comment: I purchased the episode from itunes store but when I play on my ipod 30 gb I can not see the subtitles. This is why I am trying to burn-in.

Comment: I found a drm removal software and it worked but it only works for 5 minutes of video.. And it is 45 dollars.. But it worked.. Are there any free alternatives for removing drm? I really want to buy videos from itunes store instead of downloading from torrent but I really need the subtitles as well..

Comment: (And they wonder why people torrent videos…) I am not aware of a free solution. Unfortunately there's lots of (quite spammy) software out there, it seems. As far as I can see the iPod 30GB [does not support the video](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp41) format, so you'd have to re-encode the video anyway. Does the iPod even play other videos with subtitles you have, or is that the first you're trying?

Comment: I can import sd videos to ipod 30 gb directly, but not hd videos. I bought episode 3 of season 1 the show "24" and I can play it fine in my ipod 30gb, but unfortunatly no subtitle.. I also bought 1 episode Walking Dead but itunes says it is not compatible with ipod 30 gb.. But 24 is good enough for me..

Comment: [This thread](http://digiex.net/downloads/download-center-2-0/applications/11796-requiem-4-1-remove-itunes-drm-fairplay-music-video-books.html) mentions an app (Requiem) that you can only get via Tor, and it should remove DRM too. From the looks of it, it doesn't work with iTunes 11 though. Unfortunately, I think that I can't help you any further since I don't have files to test with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using vidcoder 1.5.22 in Windows running on Parallels.